# Make array from array values and save it to a file

Tags: php, arrays

I am working on a project in which I will get an array. 
When I use `print_r($arr)` it looks like this:

```
Array
( 
    [0] => games,
    [1] => wallpapers,
    .....
)
```

What i want to do is that i want it's value to be in an array like `array('games','wallpapers')` and save it to a file called `data.txt` using `file_put_contents`.
I did it once myown using `implode()` but sometimes it gets error. Is there a good way?

Comment: Please show your own attempt which didn't work, maybe we can help you sort that out

Comment: you already have the correct array. the numbers 0,1,... are just indexes but you have the goal value.

Comment: When you write "it gets error" please post this error so we could help you.

Comment: Have you tried using `json_encode` and `json_decode` with `file_put_contents`?

Comment: Perhaps you are interested in [`var_export()`](http://pl1.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) function.

Comment: or serialize/unserialize

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialize it and save it to a file. You can do it as a comma-separated values using [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php), or as a json string using [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) or using [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php). All three of those links have excellent documentation and examples.

If you still have troubles, please edit your question with more specific details and the code you've worked on so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 <?php
  $a=array
   ( 
   0 => 'games',
   1 => 'wallpapers'
  );
   $str= implode(',',$a);
   file_put_contents('data.txt', $str);
 ?>
```

**data.txt**

```
 games,wallpapers
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the values, use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php). To store this array to disk, first [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php), then store the output anyway you like - `file_put_contents` is the simplest way I believe.